# CentOS+SeleniumServer+ChromeDriver run only on one port

Tags: google-chrome, unix, selenium, centos

After running one browser by chromdriver others fail with exception:

```html
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find a free port
  at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.findFreePort(PortProber.java:67)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:292)
  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
  at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:138)
... 14 more
13:45:41.442 WARN - Exception: Unable to find a free port
```

Selenium server try run chromedriver on the same port (1024). This port is already busy by first chromedriver. I can't understand: how to get selenium server run chromedriver on different port(not 1024). The same scheme works on Windows perfectly

I run node like this:

```html
DISPLAY=:99 xvfb-run -a -n 1 -l -s "-screen 0, 8000x2000x16" java -jar /home/autotest/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -nodeConfig nodeconfig.json
```

Runing selenium node on other port by option doesn't work.

```html
-port 5554
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range`
and edit it to read:

```
5000 65535
```